# How to change name of Scaffold without recreating it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a scaffold "example" and have made many changes to its controller and views.

Now I want to rename it to "sample", **is there any way to do it without breaking anything** ? it will be difficult to manually edit controller, model, views and migration file so I was hoping there may be something to ease up this.

Comment: There is no way.. u need to edit every thing manually.. You can use find and replace thing editor..

Comment: Do you want to change the routes? e.g. `your_host/example` to look like `your_host/sample`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's currently not possible.

You will need to edit the existing controller manually. You can use and advanced IDE, such as [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), to help you with the job.

Also, I don't suggest you to change the existing scaffold. You can create a new one, make sure it's working properly, then remove the old one.

Be careful to not rename migrations or your app it's likely to break. Migrations should not be changed once applied, to change the schema you should create a new migration.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and created new scaffold as it looked much easier